# using RESTful API (POST,PUT,GET) on NFC tags, or how to run curl on mobile universally

Tags: android, rest, curl, philips-hue

I am looking to place NFC tags around my house in order to switch on lights and other applicances which have RESTful APIs (phillips hue lights).
I can achieve this through tasker etc, but they don't work for people who do not have these apps.

I would like these NFC tags to work for almost any phone (iOS would be nice, but I feel like all android phones may be more attainable).

I believe the best route may be to use a simple shell script such as `curl`.

I can run the following from my computer, which allows me to control lights:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"on":true}' http://<bridge-ip-address>/api/<username>/groups/0/action
```

So, now the question is:

**How can I get this script to be run whenever an NFC tag is read, no matter what device activates it?**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, so there are endless solutions to this question. I would say the simplest solution would be to use NFC tags to launch a URL to control the lights/devices via a locally networked web server. You could interface hue with perl/php/etc, and the NFC tags would launch the URL, the server would convert your URL arguments to commands and send them to your hue bridge or wherever.

You could also use NFC to launch an app. I don't know much about android/iOS app dev but you could probably send commands with nfc to the app you're launching. Problem is the app would have to be installed on the client, which could be any platform.